# Multi module maven import issue in RAD 8.5

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin, rad

I have a parent pom and separate child pom.while importing whole folder in RAD 8.5 child folder is coming twice .one is inside the parent folder and one is outside parent folder.i want all child folders to be inside parent folder.

example: in eclipse:
its coming like dis.
1. parent:

child 1 child 2

2.child 1

3.child 2

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing your projects are being duplicated in the Project Explorer View, they are show in that way but if you change one of the children then changes will be reflected in the parent.

Comment: but i don't want this type of structure , i want child should be inside parent folder.one single parent folder should be shown

Comment: Ok, this is not possible for any eclipse based product like RAD as nested projects are not supported yet. Take a look to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=245412